# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined in typescript Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an issue where I am unable to compile typescript code that references the browser api. Namely `localStorage`. The project uses Angular 2 and typescript 2.1. I tried setting a type declaration at the beginning of the file but I am still getting the error. Here's the error [image: error]:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { AuthHttp } from "./auth.http";

declare var localStorage: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    authKey = "auth";

    constructor(private http: AuthHttp) {
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): any {
        var url = "api/connect/token";  // JwtProvider's LoginPath

        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            client_id: "OpenGameList",
            // required when signing up with username/password
            grant_type: "password",
            // space-separated list of scopes for which the token is issued
            scope: "offline_access profile email"
        };

        return this.http.post(
            url,
            this.toUrlEncodedString(data),
            new RequestOptions({
                headers: new Headers({
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                })
            }))
            .map(response => {
                var auth = response.json();
                console.log("The following auth JSON object has been received:");
                console.log(auth);
                this.setAuth(auth);
                return auth;
            });
    }

    logout(): boolean {
        this.setAuth(null);
        return true;
    }

    // Converts a Json object to urlencoded format
    toUrlEncodedString(data: any) {
        var body = "";
        for (var key in data) {
            if (body.length) {
                body += "&";
            }
            body += key + "=";
            body += encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
        }
        return body;
    }

    // Persist auth into localStorage or removes it if a NULL argument is given
    setAuth(auth: any): boolean {
        if (auth) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.authKey, JSON.stringify(auth));
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem(this.authKey);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Retrieves the auth JSON object (or NULL if none)
    getAuth(): any {
        var i = localStorage.getItem(this.authKey);
        if (i) {
            return JSON.parse(i);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns TRUE if the user is logged in, FALSE otherwise.
    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.authKey) != null;
    }
}
```

EDIT ----

I found out the issue. The template project recompiles the angular spa on the server where there is no `localStorage`. To compile it, I have to surround it with the following:

```
import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal';

if (isBrowser) {
    // Do stuff with localStorage
}
```

Comment: Something elsewhere in your code is calling that `isLoggedIn()` method. What's in that "vendor.js" file?

Comment: I am using microsoft's aspnet-angular 2 template(https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) which uses webpack to compile all the js files. Vendor.js is the 3rd party node packages compiled to one file.

Comment: try to write `window.localStorage` instead `localStorage`.

Comment: why do you use `declare var localStorage: any;` at top of code? localStorage is in lib.d.ts

Comment: I declared localStorage at the beginning of the file to force the compile. It didn't work. Now I am referencing window.localStorage and I am getting the following error - http://i.imgur.com/MP54Cth.png

Comment: Looks like you're getting runtime errors not compile errors. If you actually are getting compile errors about browser specific globals not being found then make sure your tsconfig.json is not specifying `"compilerOptions": {"noLib": true}`. But again this will not have any impact at runtime.

Comment: Did you get around this issue in the end @SimonTheodore?